# SEF Links with mod_rewrite error 500

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, sef

Hey i want to rewrite my links

```
mydomain.com/?page=pageName
```

to

```
mydomain.com/pageName
```

I tried with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

but it seems to to give an error 500

Comment: Look into the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because of your rule.
You must add a condition to avoid it

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT: taking your comments into consideration

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.php)?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that and it still seems to return error 500

Comment: Did you try with my code only or do you have other rules ? Also, do you have `index` (like `index.php` or other) in your url or is it simply `/?page=xxx` ?

Comment: No I dont have any other rules and yes I have index.php

Comment: Still error 500. Could it be something from my server settings ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot something in my code. I edited my answer, should be working as expected now

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but what if i want to add another variable for example.


  `index.php?page=news&id=1`

i tried adding

  `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]`
but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: It should be working, your rule is correct. What url did you try and did not work ?

Comment: Do you get an error ? Do you have other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: Actually i made work but for some reason the css is not loading

Comment: That's because this rule creates a virtual directory and you're using relative paths for all your html links. Instead, use absolute paths. You can see a similar question (and my answer to solve the problem) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778481/htaccess-pulling-text-to-left/25787607#25787607

Comment: Hmm I tried with rewritebase and base tag in the header. Even with absolute links it still doesnt load the css. I think it just picks up everything after the root and thinks its a GET variable and rewrites it. This only happens with 2nd variable in the rewrite rule.

Comment: You can see my "edit" part (in answer) about it. Should be working as expected