# .htaccess pulling text to left

Tags: .htaccess

So the problem is, when I use only the first parameter, the page works like a charm, but when I use the second one, my CSS gets messed up (text alignment -> left)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&user=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

dummy.com/mode
dummy.com/mode/
*Works!*

dummy.com/mode/user
dummy.com/mode/user/
*Aligns text to left!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths for all your html links (images, javascript, css, href links).

Actually, your rules create virtual directories.
That's why i'm surprised `dummy.com/mode/` (with trailing slash) also works.

Let's say you have css links that way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

For all your examples, here is the path resolution

- `dummy.com/mode` -> */css/style.css*
- `dummy.com/mode/` -> */mode/css/style.css*
- `dummy.com/mode/user` -> */mode/css/style.css*
- `dummy.com/mode/user/` -> */mode/user/css/style.css*

Can you see the problem now ?
To avoid that behaviour, use **absolute** path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Or, if you don't want to change all your html links, you can add this line after `<head>` html tag

```
<base href="/">
```

**Note 1**: assuming for absolute path that everything was in root folder.

**Note 2**: you should add a `RewriteBase` in your htaccess (to avoid same problem with virtual directories)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&user=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

**Note 3**: you should avoid `/?` in the end of your rules (which means `/` is optional) because it creates 2 different urls with same content (this is called duplicate content and that's not good for search engines).

*Make a choice: with or without trailing slash but not both*.

Comment: Justin, you're golden! Well written and understandable post!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Basically when you will pull the URL of resources, the check will do perform empty check and result nothing.

I had similar problem when my style url would direct me to the the php handler page, so this is what I assume happens to you.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # avoiding directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not checking if is a file, commented out
# must be located before all other rules
RewriteRule ^([.+/]*.*[.+].+)$ - [L] # file must be skipped

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&user=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```