# htaccess not rewriting url for my GET requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following url to bring in all my page templates:

`www.example.com/tournament/index.php?view=*`

I want to rewrite this to

`www.example.com/tournament/*`

so

`www.example.com/tournament/index.php?view=profile` becomes `www.example.com/tournament/profile`

and

`www.example.com/tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=testUser` becomes `www.example.com/tournament/profile/testUser`.

I currently have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^tournament/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^tournament/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tournament/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^tournament/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tournament/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^tournament/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2
```

but this is not working. I have `RewriteEngine On` as well.

The following file structure is:

```
|public
|->tournament
    |->templates
        |-> profile.php
    |->index.php
    |->.htaccess (with rewriting in)
```

Thanks in advance.

**edit *index.php***

```
<?php
    include '../../includes/functions.php';

    sec_session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $user = new user($db, $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['lastActive']);
    }

    include INCLUDESPATH . 'form_actions.php';
    include "headers/header.php";
    include "headers/navbar.php";

    echo '<div class="wrapper">';

    $view = 'index';
    if (!empty($_GET['view'])) {
        $tmp_view = basename($_GET['view']);

        if (file_exists("templates/{$tmp_view}.php")) {
            $view = $tmp_view;
            include "templates/{$view}.php";
        }
        else {
            include "errors/404.php";
        }

    }

    echo '</div>';

    include "headers/footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your htaccess is located in `tournament` folder, you can have it this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tournament/

# Redirect /tournament/index.php?view=XXX to /tournament/XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect /tournament/index.php?view=XXX&id=YYY to /tournament/XXX/YYY
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)&id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

# Skip if existing file/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Internally rewrite them back
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: the rewrite worked however now my page's css/js files wont load through; check my update on my question regarding how I pull my template files through with the ?view=*

Comment: You'll need to use absolute paths instead of relative paths for all your resources such as js, css, etc. If you need help, please read this answer i wrote about your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778481/htaccess-pulling-text-to-left/25787607#25787607

Comment: Working great so far just one more question.. usually i'd do `<a href="?view=profile&id=matt500b&edit=true"` (of course the id would be dynamic) how can I now use `<a>` ? since pressing the edit button just makes my url go `.../tournament/profile/matt500b?view=profile&id=matt500b&edit=true` (I added another rule following your layout for the 3rd url so manually going to `.../tournament/profile/matt500b/edit` works)

Comment: Well you have two solutions. First one (the laziest) is to keep your actual html links and rely on the htaccess to redirect *old* links to *new* links when needed. Second one (the cleanest) is to replace all your *old* html links by (directly) corresponding *new* links. For instance, you'd have `<a href="/tournament/profile/matt500b/edit">edit</a>` instead of the `index.php?view=xxx&id=yyy&edit=true` version

Answer (score 1):

The following rule can handle both of your urls :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tournament/index.php\?view=([^&]+)&id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tournament/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:tournament/)?([^/]+)/?(.*)/?$ /tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not changing" ? what url did you type in the browser?

Comment: http://dev2.csgoberry.com/tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=matt500b

I am expecting this to change to `http://dev2.csgoberry.com/tournament/profile/matt500b/` but nothing happens

Comment: the rewrite worked however now my page wont load at all; check my update on my question regarding how I pull my template files through with the ?view=*

Comment: If its a css and js related issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: for this version of htaccess the page gets an `Internal Server Error`. The version by _Justin lurman_ has an issue with css/js which i'm attempting to fix now.

Comment: I think the error is because of internal redirect conflicting with files and folders, i have added conditions to exclude them.

Comment: The new conditions worked but found it easier to edit Justins rules to include further variables in the url. upvoted for a working answer though thank you!