# htaccess rewrite for different get parameters at the same level

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Firstly I asked this question [on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654459/htaccess-not-rewriting-url-for-my-get-requests) to get url rewriting working. I extended this to include a 3rd parameter however I failed when this 3rd parameter is different.

I have created a list of a few urls I currently have with their GET parameters and what I want to turn them into:

```
~/tournament/profile/username           /tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=username
~/tournament/profile/username/edit      /tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=username&action=edit
~/tournament/profile/username/overview  /tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=username&page=overview
~/tournament/profile/username/teams     /tournament/index.php?view=profile&id=username&page=teams


~/tournament/teams/create               /tournament/index.php?view=teams&action=create
~/tournament/teams/teamname             /tournament/index.php?view=teams&id=teamname
~/tournament/teams/teamname/edit        /tournament/index.php?view=teams&id=teamname&action=edit
~/tournament/teams/teamname/delete      /tournament/index.php?view=teams&id=teamname&action=delete
~/tournament/teams/teamname/members     /tournament/index.php?view=teams&id=teamname&page=members

~/tournament/cups                       /tournament/index.php?view=cups
~/tournament/cups/id                    /tournament/index.php?view=cups&id=cupid
~/tournament/cups/id/rules              /tournament/index.php?view=cups&page=rules
~/tournament/cups/id/matches            /tournament/index.php?view=cups&page=matches
~/tournament/cups/id/brackets           /tournament/index.php?view=cups&page=brackets
~/tournament/cups/id/teams              /tournament/index.php?view=cups&page=teams

~/tournament/passwords/forgot_password  /tournament/index.php?view=password&action=forgot_password
~/tournament/passwords/reset            /tournament/index.php?view=password&action=reset

~/tournament/admin                      /tournament/admin.php
~/tournament/admin/users                /tournament/admin.php?view=users
~/tournament/admin/users/username       /tournament/admin.php?view=users&id=username
```

using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tournament/

# Skip if existing file/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)&id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)&id=([^&\s]+)&action=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/$3? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)&id=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/$3? [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

mostly focusing on the urls regarding `/profile/username/edit` and `/profile/username/overview`.

I added in the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/tournament/index\.php\?view=([^&\s]+)&id=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/$3? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1&id=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

to deal with the `&page` parameter however when my url rewrites to `/profile/username/team/overview` I get my edit page back rather than the overview page.

What is the most efficient way to deal with interchanging variables? i.e.

`?view=*&id=*&action=*` vs `?view=*&id=*&page=*`

Thanks again.

Comment: Is "action=edit" a dyanamic keyword?

Comment: @starkeen what do you mean? `action=*` represents an editing/creating/deleting of something with forms, otherwise it'll usually be displaying data using `ids/pages` etc

Comment: Matt sorry, I meant **edit** is this a fixed path segment?

Comment: No in my profiles template I split the data being shown using the get params (if isset $edit && isset $id show edit page) in short

Answer (score 0):

You can use single entry point technique.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tournament/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now you need to parse the requested URL in index.php to obtain parameters. Something like that:

```
$view = 'default';
$id = '0';
$params = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/') {
    try {
        $url_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $uri_parts = explode('/', trim($url_path, ' /'));

        if (count($uri_parts) % 2) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        $view = array_shift($uri_parts); 
        $id = array_shift($uri_parts);

        // /key1/value1/key2/value2 -> array()
        for ($i=0; $i < count($uri_parts); $i++) {
            $params[$uri_parts[$i]] = $uri_parts[++$i];
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $module = '404';
        $action = 'main';
    }
}
```

Comment: using this technique how would i choose which template to bring in, which data to show on the template etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect from "/tournament/index.php?view=foo&id=bar&action=edit" to "/tournament/foo/bar/edit"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tournament/index.php\?view=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)&action=(edit)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tournament/%1/%2/%3? [L,R]
#redirect from "/tournament/index.php?view=foo&id=bar" to "/tournament/foo/bar/"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tournament/index.php\?view=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)\sHT [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tournament/%1/%2? [L,R]
#redirect from "/tournament/index.php?view=foo" to "/tournament/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tournament/index.php\?view=([^&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tournament/%1? [L,R]
#internally rewrite external requests to orignal location
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?(.*?)/?$ /tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Put this rule bellow the conditions  `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` this rewrites to **?action**  when **/edit** is present in the url:

    `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/edit/?$ /tournament/index.php?view=$1&id=$2&action=edit [NC,L]`

Comment: This just gives me a 500 internal server error again :(